# Duplicate Dependencies between Bower and NPM

Tags: angularjs, bower, browserify, angular-ui-grid

I'm attempting to use [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) in an Angular project by installing it with Bower and using Debowerify and Browserify within Gulp to package it all up into one monolith js file.

We already have Angular 1.3.14 included via NPM. However, the angular-ui-grid bower package has a dependency on Angular 1.2.16, so that version of Angular gets installed as a Bower package.

When Browserify does its thing, the debowerify transform causes all references to Angular to look in the bower_components folder, not the node_modules folder.

Is there a way to specify that browserify should debowerify certain modules, but not others? How can we avoid having both an Angular node module and an Angular bower package?